# C# WinForms drawing a Bitmap on a PictureBox draws too many times

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I use a C# WinForms application with some PictureBoxes in there.
I drew some figures, at first (because of the size of the boxes) I didn't notice an error,
but after a few boxes I noticed, that my code ran fine,
but the images drawn were wrong.
It was as if the drawing methods were called many more times than in the debugger.

As you can see here:

[[image: error drawing]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE06K.png)

I ran my code multiple times,
had `DoubleBuffering` enabled/disabled for the Form, same behavior.
I used break points to see if I called the drawing more than once in my code,

but no, it was called once.  I always use this in a method:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Resources.<backgroundfile>, 342, 54);
    RectangleF rectfLage = new RectangleF(16, 14, 60, 22);
    Graphics graphicLageNr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    graphicLageNr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphicLageNr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphicLageNr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    graphicLageNr.DrawString($"{lage}", new Font("Tahoma", 16), Brushes.Black, rectfLage);
    graphicLageNr.Flush();
```

After that, I set the Background of the PictureBox to NULL and then to the Bitmap.

```
    Controls[0].Controls[2].Controls["lagenr"].BackgroundImage = null
    Controls[0].Controls[2].Controls["lagenr"].BackgroundImage = bmp
```

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Show use your entire method - not just a few lines. What event or method is this being called from?

Comment: That is the important part of the method. The rest of the method handles the correct formatting of some values that are also inserted there. The method is called when the index of a DataGridView is changed.

Comment: Please consider that I might have quite legitimate reasons for wanting to see your **full method including signature line** and not just what you subjectvely think is "the important part" - because the evidence suggests that you are executing GDI drawing commands at the wrong times in the application window message event loop and that is what is causing you problems. That's is why I asked.

Comment: If thats all then it should be easy for you to write an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) around that bit of code so we can "see" the problem ourselved when executing that. As you mentioned DataGridView if you paint inside a grid cell then yes the grids own paint/repaint behavior might be in the way.

Comment: _As you can see here_ Um, no I can't see what is wong because I don't know what would be right.  Any reason why you use Flush ?? Also: Some things are next to impossible to debug, especially when they depend on user interactions.. You may need to log out hints.

Comment: Thanks for all your time, solved it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
All I had to do was setting the right mode.
`Picturebox.SizeMode` has to be `CenterImage`.
Also assigning a `Bitmap` to a `PictureBox`needed to be like this:
`((PictureBox)Controls[0].Controls[2].Controls[pb_name]).Image`